# php strtotime not working

Tags: php, time, timestamp, strtotime

so I converted this string to timestamp using strtotime:

```
strtotime("1 Nov, 2001");
```

which results into the timestamp 1320177660

but then when I tried converted 1320177660 into a normal date format again using an online timestamp converter, the year ended up being 2011 rather than 2001...

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's interpreting the "2001" as time (HHMM), not year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Evan Mulawski's comment says, the "2001" is being interpreted as the time, not the year.  Take out the comma to get PHP to interpret the "2001" as a year:

```
<?php
$ts = strtotime("1 Nov 2001");
echo $ts . "\n";
$st = strftime("%B %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S", $ts);
echo $st . "\n";
?>
```

Output:

> 1004590800
>   November 01, 2001, 00:00:00

Answer (score 4):

You're not doing anything wrong - it's just that [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) isn't infallible.

As such, if you know the string is always going to be in a certain format, it's sometimes advisable to parse the date yourself, or if you're running PHP 5.3.x, you could use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the string for you.

Answer (score 0):

If strtotime() is not working then try this

**strtotime(str_replace('/','', $date ));**

It will work properly. Don't use '/' in date, because when you will format this then it may detect this type of issue. Thanks