# php strtotime return wrong timestamp

Tags: php, time, timestamp, strtotime

I'm using php strtotime function 
(date format `Day, month and two digit year, with dots or tabs` d.m.y from doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) 
and found problem:

From php.net example strtotime("30.6.08") -> 1214773200 -> Sun, 29 Jun 2008 21:00:00 GMT(reverse convert right)

another variant strtotime("24.10.13") -> 1381180213 -> Mon, 07 Oct 2013 21:10:13 GMT (reverse is not right)

but strtotime("30.10.13") -> 1383084000 -> Tue, 29 Oct 2013 22:00:00 GMT (reverse result again correctly)

Whats wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php strtotime not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680056/php-strtotime-not-working)

Comment: strtotime isn't infallible - if you know the format, you should use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) (available from PHP 5.3.x and above) or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Strtotime` is guessing what format you are sending the date in as and guessing wrong. You should use `DateTime()` where you can specify the format you are sending the date in as.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y', $datestring);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: For me, using DateTime doesn't solve this issue. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I eventually solved it. THe client database was actually sending me incorrect dates such as "00-00-2014". That is why I was having strange behaviour, but PHP was doing the job correctly, the problem was between the chair and the desk